# Why does my java-application fail to find a file on usb?

Tags: java, pdf, file-io, ioexception

Based on [this solution](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-java/) I'm accessing a pdf-File. Code is as follows:

```
editor.getMntmNewMenuItem().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {

            File pdfFile = new File("Ressources\\test.pdf");
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {

                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    System.out.println(pdfFile.getCanonicalPath());
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
                } else {
                throw new Exception("Desktop wird nicht unterstützt!");
                }
            } 
            else {
                throw new Exception("Datei ist nichtdd vorhanden! ");
            }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {
                    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("stacktrace.txt"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ex.printStackTrace(pw);
                pw.append("\n\nUSER DIR: + " +System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                pw.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(editor.getContentPane(), ex.getMessage(), "Fehler",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
        });
```

File-structure is as follows:

1. editor.jar
2. Ressources
3. |-----test.pdf

This is the full stackTrace:

> java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/E://Ressources/test.pdf. Error message:The system cannot find the file specified.

```
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
at iscms.ISCMS$2$20.actionPerformed(ISCMS.java:877)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    USER DIR: = E:\
```

This works perfectly on my pc and in eclipse, but on my usb stick it doesn't work. I get an IOException for some reason. What am I missing?

Comment: What does the `IOException` say the problem was? Please post the message and full stack trace.

Comment: Also, print the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` in each case...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies! Added the stack trace and the the result of System.getProperty("user.dir").

Comment: Please post the error messages in english, thank you.

Comment: I'll consider it for the future! I edited the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below actually works. I'm not using the relative path any more, instead I use `System.get.property("user.dir")`. I don't know if this is nice and clean, but why complain if this works? It doesn't answer the question, but it certainly solved my problem.

```
        editor.getMntmNewMenuItem().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
            String userDir=System.getProperty("user.dir");
            File pdfFile = new File(userDir+"\\Ressources\\test.pdf");
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {

                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
                } else {
                throw new Exception("Desktop wird nicht unterstützt!");
                }
            } 
            else {
                throw new Exception("Datei ist nicht vorhanden! ");
            }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(editor.getContentPane(), ex.getMessage(), "Fehler",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
        });
```